# MariaDB View not working but statement does

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, sql-view, sqldatetime

My new hosting provider is running MySQL Version 10.0.31-MariaDB-cll-lve

I have a view that was working fine in MySQL 5.6 but does not work in MariaDB.

I have created a simple cut down version just to show what is causing an error.

I can create the view but I can not use it:

```
CREATE VIEW `test_date` 
AS select (case 
   when (now() between '2018-01-01 00:00:00' and '2018-06-30 23:59:59') 
     then '2018-06-30' 
   else NULL end) - interval 4 month
```

The error I get when trying to open:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use 
near '21:05:05 between 2018-01-01 00:00:00 and 2018-06-30 23:59:59) 
then '2018-06-30' ' at line 1
```

I can't see anything wrong and it works fine on normal MySQL servers.

I have tried removing the '- interval 4 month' and it works fine:

```
CREATE VIEW `test_date` 
AS select case 
  when (now() between '2018-01-01 00:00:00' and '2018-06-30 23:59:59') 
    then '2018-06-30' 
  else NULL end
```

I have tried replacing the dates with simple numbers and it works fine:

```
CREATE VIEW `test_date` 
AS select (case 
   when (3 between 1 and 5) 
     then '2018-06-30' 
   else NULL end) - interval 4 month
```

So what is the real problem here? I am stumped.

Comment: You are using string literals here. Is this the same in your real view? If you want date literals, use the ANSI syntax, where the string is preceded by the `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` keyword. E.g. `timestamp '2018-01-01 00:00:00'` or `date '2018-01-01'`.

Comment: With time ranges `BETWEEN` is not recommended, because of time precision. Use `case when now() >= date '2018-01-01' and now() < date '2018-07-01' then` instead. Or use dates without time parts only: `case when current_date between date '2018-01-01' and date '2018-06-30' then`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'2018-06-30' is not implicitly converting to a date (I guess this is one of the things that has been tightened up between mysql versions or the fork that is mariadb) try explicitly converting it.

```
drop view if exists test_date;
CREATE VIEW `test_date` AS 
select (case when (now() between '2018-01-01 00:00:00' and '2018-06-30 23:59:59') then str_to_date('2018-06-30','%Y-%m-%d') else NULL end) 
- interval 4 month;

select * from test_date;

+------------+
| Name_exp_1 |
+------------+
| 2018-02-28 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Oddly the select alone works fine it's only when used in a view (possibly in conjunction with a between statement) that it doesn't

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select (case
    ->    when (now() between '2018-01-01 00:00:00' and '2018-06-30 23:59:59')
    ->      then '2018-06-30'
    ->    else NULL end) - interval 4 month rd;
+------------+
| rd         |
+------------+
| 2018-02-28 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

When used in a view an error is thrown

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> create view test_date as
    -> select
    -> (
    -> case when (now() between '2018-01-01 00:00:00' and '2018-06-30 23:59:59') then '2018-06-30'
    -> else NULL
    -> end
    -> ) - interval 4 month as rd
    -> ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select rd from test_date;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '08:16:57 between 2018-01-01 00:00:00 and 2018-06-30 23:59:59) then '2018-06-30' ' at line 1
```

If the between statement is replaced by >=,<=

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> create view test_date as
    -> select
    -> (
    -> case when (now() >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00' and now() <= '2018-06-30 23:59:59') then '2018-06-30'
    -> else NULL
    -> end
    -> ) - interval 4 month as rd
    -> ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select rd from test_date;
+------------+
| rd         |
+------------+
| 2018-02-28 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to have fixed it. Any idea why in my last example it works? Seems odd it would convert it to a date in that example.

Comment: After a bit more testing this begins to look like a bug to me. I have added some detail to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for adding more detail, yeah the logic just doesn't make sense to me. I can't understand why as a view it would execute differently then the statement itself.